# What XPath to select only non-taged text inside div. Selenium. Java

Tags: java, html, xpath, selenium

I want to select only the text "only this text" from the snipet below using XPath (in Java) but that text is **random** and I don't know what is written there.

```
 <div class="A">
    <input id="button" type="button">x</input>
    only this random text
 </div>
```

What is the simplest xpath?

```
 //div[@class='A'][what next?]
```

I saw similar questions but answers are always too complicated and I would like to know the simplest way.

Also is there any other way, without using XPath (in Java),to get that text?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can select text nodes using the axis step `text()`.

```
//div[@class='A']/text()
```

If you only want text nodes following the `<input/>` node, use this:

```
//div[@class="A"]/input/following-sibling::text()
```

You can add arbitrary predicates to the `<input/>` element, too - like you did for the `<div/>`.

Comment: I guess the original question was a little unspecific. Hadn't got it either without the comments on your question...

Comment: '//div[@class='A']/text()' is working but I get "text element" not "WebElement" and I get error in JUnit "text() is either invalid or does not result in a WebElement"

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
//div[@class='A']/node()[not(self::input)]
```

But it returns text element, now WebElement
It seems there is no way to retrieve it as a WebElement because the text should be an element like this:

```
<div class="A">
    <input id="button" type="button">x</input>
    <text>only this random text</text>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Locate using the `parent` tag and use .

If there is not tag for the text inside the div tag.

```
div[@class='A']
```

[contains(.,'only this random text')]

Answer (score 0):

You can also find it using:

```
//div[.='what next?']
```

So, it will return an **item(div)** which contains this value.

But keep in mind that it's a generic mapping, if you have multiple items with this value on the screen it won't be that accurate.